# How can two equations with three variables be in R2, not in R3?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I am currently taking 18-06sc Linear Algebra from MIT's Opencourseware. One of the things that has baffled me is how a 2x3 matrix is in R2. In my mind the underlying equations in this matrix would be:

2x + 3y + 7z = 4

1x + 2y + 3z = 10

Since each one of these equations has three variables, graphing it would create a plane in R3. This seems to contradict the fact that the matrix form of these two equations would be in R2. please help me understand this.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a quick tutorial for mathjax. With that, you can write goodlooking formulas.

Comment: I think there is a lot of potential in this question and look forward to reading responses.

Comment: What makes you say that the matrix from would be in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: It makes no sense to say a $2 \times 3$ matrix is in $\mathbb R^2$. Can you please clarify what you think this means or where you heard this?

Comment: It's hard to understand this question, but the augmented matrix for the system you've written is $2\times 4$, not $2\times 3$.  A $2\times 3$ augmented matrix would have corresponding equations in two variables.

Comment: There are many ways in which to view your equations. For one they can be seen as a linear combination of three vectors and the resultant.  $x(2,1)^T+y (3,2)^T+z (7,3)^T=(4,10)^T $.

Comment: @pjs36 I think what I mean is that the column space is in $\Bbb R^2$

Answer (score 2):

A $2 \times 3$ matrix represents a linear transformation **from** $\Bbb R^3$  **to** $\Bbb R^2$.

For your example, $M = \begin{bmatrix}2&3&7 \\ 1&2&3\end{bmatrix}$ takes a vector ${\mathbf v} = \begin{bmatrix} x \\y \\z\end{bmatrix} \in \Bbb R^3$ and sends it to the vector $$M{\bf v} = \begin{bmatrix}2&3&7 \\ 1&2&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\y \\z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2x + 3y + 7z \\ x + 2y + 3z\end{bmatrix} \in \Bbb R^2.$$

You're right that geometrically, each single equation determines a two-dimensional plane,

\begin{align*}
P_1 &= \{(x, y, z) \in \Bbb R^3 : 2x + 3y + 7z = 4\} \quad {\rm and} \\
P_2 &= \{(x, y, z) \in \Bbb R^3 : x + 2y + 3z = 10\}, 
\end{align*}

each of which is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

To solve both equations simultaneously amounts to finding all solutions of $$M{\bf v} = \begin{bmatrix}4 \\ 10\end{bmatrix},$$

which corresponds geometrically to finding the intersection $P_1 \cap P_2$ of those two planes, which will be a line in $\Bbb R^3$. This will be the (one-dimensional) subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ that gets sent to the point $\begin{bmatrix}4 \\ 10\end{bmatrix}$ by the matrix $M$.

Comment: I would like, later, to add some images of the two planes and their intersection. But not now, unfortunately!

Comment: This was a nice answer. I don't think this is stressed enough when matrices are introduced. This was exactly the type of answer I hoped to see +1

Comment: Thank you, @Karl ! I've been stewing on what kind of images to add. There's also a mistake I plan to fix when I add the images (I claim that $P_1 \cap P_2$ is a subspace -- it's instead a *translate* of a subspace! This last remark was really a warning for whomever may be attempting to learn from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I could understand, your trouble is understanding. So, every of those two equations do lie in $R^3$ but their intersection do not need to lie there.The fact that their intersection lie in $R^2$ means there is some plane containing their intersection. To see this, eliminate one of the variables and ypu will be left with one equation of form $ay+bz=0$ which is a plane and other will be in $R^3$ and it will all come clear.

Comment: Their intersection does not lie in $\mathbb R^2$.